# Bash echo special character

Tags: bash

I want to print out below string literally with `echo`

```
"${placeholder.test}" '(
```

I have looked at all similar issues and here are what I have tried

`echo ""${placeholder.test}" '("` gives bad substitution error

`echo '"${placeholder.test}" '('` gives unexpected token `('

`echo '"${placeholder.test}" '\('` command not exit unless I enter another `'`

I also tried `printf` but same issues

any solution?

Comment: You need to escape the `$` character. This works fine in my shell. `echo \"\${placeholder.test}\"" '("`

Comment: Try: `echo "\"\${placeholder.test}\" '("`. Result `"${placeholder.test}" '(`

Comment: `echo $'"${placeholder.test}" \'('`

Comment: `placeholder.test` is not a valid variable name. That's what causes _bad substitution_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `here-doc` to avoid any escaping:

```bash
cat <<-'EOF'
"${placeholder.test}" '(
EOF
```

However if you really want to use `echo` then use:

```bash
echo '"${placeholder.test}" '"'("

"${placeholder.test}" '(
```

Comment: thanks, I like you cat solution since it does not need extra modification to original string

Comment: @user3908406 It's not `cat` that's special; it's really the heredoc -- the `<<'EOF'` part -- that's important. You could for example use `IFS= read -r mystring <<'EOF'`, populate the variable, then `echo "$mystring"` to print it.

Answer (score 0):

With [ANSI-C quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), single quotes can be escaped:

```bash
var=$'"${placeholder.test}" \'('
echo "$var"
```

That apparently messes up the syntax highlighting here. Can't use regexes for everything...